# How to serialize list or array using MetaLama in ToString TypeAspect

Tags: c#, metalama

I am trying to write an TypeAspect using MetaLama framwerok that will serialize an object to it's string representation when it has a nested list type.
Here is what I tried :

```
public class ToStringAttribute : TypeAspect
    {
        [Introduce(WhenExists = OverrideStrategy.Override, Name = "ToString")]
        public string IntroducedToString()
        {
            var stringBuilder = new InterpolatedStringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.AddText(meta.Target.Type.Name);
            stringBuilder.AddText(" ");

            var fields = meta.Target.Type.FieldsAndProperties.Where(f => !f.IsStatic)
                                                             .ToList();

            var i = meta.CompileTime(0);

            stringBuilder.AddText("{ ");
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AddText(", ");
                }

                stringBuilder.AddText(field.Name);
                stringBuilder.AddText(" : ");
                if (field.Type.ToType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    stringBuilder.AddText("'");
                    stringBuilder.AddExpression(field.Invokers.Final.GetValue(meta.This));
                    stringBuilder.AddText("'");
                }
                else if ((field.Type.ToType().IsArray || field.Type.ToType().IsCollectible) && !field.Type.ToType().IsPrimitive) // <- not filtering collection types
                {
                    stringBuilder.AddText("[");
                    //foreach (var item in meta.Target.Type.FieldsAndProperties.Where(p => p.Type.ToType().IsCollectible)) <- I need the collection type properties
                    //{
                    //stringBuilder.AddExpression(item);
                    //stringBuilder.AddText(" : ");
                    //stringBuilder.AddExpression(item.Value);
                    //}
                    stringBuilder.AddText("]");
                }
                else
                {
                    stringBuilder.AddExpression(field.Invokers.Final.GetValue(meta.This));
                }

                i++;
            }
            stringBuilder.AddText(" }");

            return stringBuilder.ToValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help? Am new with MetaLama, but I found it very interesting.
thnx

Answer (score 1):

This code will check if a type is enumerable:

```cs
var returnsEnumerable =
 type is INamedType namedType 
  && !type.Is( SpecialType.String )
  && namedType.AllImplementedInterfaces.Any( i => i.Name == "IEnumerable" );
```

You can [try it online](https://try.metalama.net/#N4IghiBcIPQwBAFQBYEsDO8PzAO3gPYAOAprgLToECuATgMYnwCyJALmADZgC2Y8JAB68inEgDp4AZRJNkbNkXSQ4Ac1Rtk1AEbj6BHjCIF0bdMjC0iMVh259xUkWMwAzArXg8PEgDq5-anRUXFUWdi5eMHEAMVpeEgB3DwBrcQBhAgATEgBuQODQ8Lso2PieJNTxAEF0UnozfIDcIh1OVHp4em50TEQSU2qFWlRtajYmSHgAeQA3EloRnNtkbNr6tn9gf3hd+Fbtds6CecXUHPgsgE9cXg6AfhnTpZIV7IAKAEodve38PYBs0s8DYV1I8AAvF4IuJEJZVOxxG8suIAErsOi4RBgvL+H4A3ZAzy0DG0XDoACiuGoFXihyYEPxBIBoPB2AAkgA5BJZbHg24VXk4+BM5l7ABk4vgAEJWRJ2eh3tJ6qguHyJFI2CMit9-mKAZL4AKSELSDVOJx2TxRCQKrgJll2faFq4wIx0DVcFclahIQA+LDibkVSFQ3wgdlUmkLMD08PwT5NUV7TLkghicQAdRGEwAMiESO8ACThhXwADkwDlAF9ywJqbTY2JHsASWxMZSGzH6dXw4m8XqCW3MdCOOIAAq0AiME1fJoA3u4asgAA0ICIUFgCBQ2GweEIpAoVDojGKkT4AmE1oz0lk8HkimUag0Wl0+kMxlM5ks1ls5+iTjXgM8DuJ43gkuIA4hBMZJcF0PSYJOBCqOUWxMkQIxAhM8CmGAbAdPAswEOcLBgCEXxMn8+pMouTIANr9KYAC66GYXhTC4fhnTQfA6LtmS6BOmwXz+vAAAMSaDgxAxsCxg4YagWEcRwXHwPmpgADzQQGfEdupwmfKJ1IWtKkkAtJzGsYp7E4SpBGmNqYS6QJmqOSJEIBsZnCmQOAL+Mu1ZAA):